# C / C++ clearer #includes

Tags: c++, c, include

I really don't like when I have to navigate backwards in my includes.
I'd mutch more prefere if there would be a way to avoid that. Look at this folder for example:

[image]

Is there any way to tell the compiler (gcc) to start looking for includes from RootFolder, so I can say `#include "Logic/Entitiy/Player.h"` in my MainView.h/c or anywhere else, so I can avoid that unappealing backwards navigations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass include directories to your compiler. The configuration depends on the compiler. For gcc you set an include directory with `-I`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Answer (score 1):

include your RootFolder to compile stage like `-I "RootFolder"` then you can use `#include "Logic/Entitiy/Player.h"` just what you want.